# Image inside Stack not taking parent border radius

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need your help. I am trying to replicate a design I saw from Instagram for personal growth. I have an Image inside Stack, the Stack is a child to a Container with Border radius. However, the image inside the box doesn't take after the border radius. I have tried different methods but none of them worked.

What I am getting is

[image]

VS what I am trying to get

[image]

How can I make the image have a border radius even though is Positioned outside the box ??

Here is a snippet of my code

```
Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 500,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: boxColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                right: -150,
                top: -200,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  child:Image.asset(
                    height: width*.35,
                    width: width*.35,
                    "assets/box.png",
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,` on container

```dart
Container(
  width: 300,
  height: 500,
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
  ),
```

If you still like to use `ClipRRect` use it on top of container.